# Installed gem but getting cannot load such file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have done the following

```
gem install crack
```

And added

```
gem 'crack'
```

To my gemfile.

I am then requiring `require 'crack'`

The error I get when I try and load the route is

```
cannot load such file -- crack
```

I have run `gem environment` and get the following

```
RubyGems Environment:
- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.2.2
- RUBY VERSION: 2.1.0 (2013-12-25 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-darwin12.0]
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/joshuahornby/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/joshuahornby/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/joshuahornby/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin
- SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/joshuahornby/.gem/specs
- RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
- ruby
- x86_64-darwin-12
- GEM PATHS:
 - /Users/joshuahornby/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0
 - /Users/joshuahornby/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global
- GEM CONFIGURATION:
 - :update_sources => true
 - :verbose => true
 - :backtrace => false
 - :bulk_threshold => 1000
 - "gem" => "--no-document"
- REMOTE SOURCES:
 - https://rubygems.org/
- SHELL PATH:
 - /Users/joshuahornby/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin
 - /Users/joshuahornby/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/bin
 - /Users/joshuahornby/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin
 - /Users/joshuahornby/.rvm/bin
 - /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/bin
 - /usr/bin
 - /bin
 - /usr/sbin
 - /sbin
 - /usr/local/bin
```

Error trace

```
activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:212:in `block in load_dependency'
activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:616:in `new_constants_in'
activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:212:in `load_dependency'
activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
app/controllers/currencies_controller.rb:3:in `<class:CurrenciesController>'
app/controllers/currencies_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:424:in `load'
activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:424:in `block in load_file'
activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:616:in `new_constants_in'
activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:423:in `load_file'
activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require_or_load'
activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:463:in `load_missing_constant'
activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:226:in `const_get'
activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:226:in `block in constantize'
activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `each'
activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `inject'
activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `constantize'
activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:535:in `get'
activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:566:in `constantize'
actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `controller_reference'
actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:66:in `controller'
actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:44:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:680:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.3) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
 activerecord (4.0.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
 activerecord (4.0.3) lib/active_record/migration.rb:369:in `call'
 actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
 activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__3271670212178920711__call__callbacks'
 activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
 actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
 actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
 actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
 actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
 actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
 railties (4.0.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
 railties (4.0.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
 activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
 activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
 activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
 railties (4.0.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
 actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
 rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
 activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
railties (4.0.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
railties (4.0.3) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
/Users/joshuahornby/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/Users/joshuahornby/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/Users/joshuahornby/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
This error occurred while loading the following files:
crack
```

I am guessing it something to do with my ruby version?

Comment: Try running `bundle install`

Comment: I have run bundle install, crack is there but still getting the error.

Comment: Run `bundle show crack` and see if you get the location of the installed gem.

Comment: /Users/joshuahornby/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/crack-0.4.2

Comment: post the error trace and the code where you are doing the require

Comment: @joshuahornby10 Run `bundle env` and share the `GEM_PATH`.

Comment: The GEM_PATH is /Users/joshuahornby/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0:/Users/joshuahornby/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global

Comment: `bundle show crack` is deprecated and is now `bundle info crack`

Answer (score 15):

Your Gem Path is referring to Ruby 2.1.0

```
- GEM PATHS:
 - /Users/joshuahornby/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0
```

whereas `crack` gem is installed for Ruby 2.0.0-p353

```
/Users/joshuahornby/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/crack-0.4.2
```

This is the problem. I simulated the same installation like yours and my GEM_PATH matches to the `crack` gem path.

Here is what I recommend. First uninstall the gem crack.
In your `application path` run `rvm use 2.1.0` and then do `bundle install`.